# Kotlin support for JDBI SqlObject gives UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: kotlin, dropwizard, jdbi

Extending the Kotlin equivalent of the Dropwizard JDBI3 setup listed [in the official Dropwizard documentation](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/manual/jdbi3.html), I fail to get automatic parameter binding without `@Bind` and the Kotlin-specific mapping magic for JDBI to work as shown in [Kotlin support for SqlObject](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/tree/master/kotlin-sqlobject). Instead of this...

```
data class Thing(val id: Int, val name: String,
                 val nullable: String?,
                 val nullableDefaultedNull: String? = null,
                 val nullableDefaultedNotNull: String? = "not null",
                 val defaulted: String = "default value")

interface ThingDao {
    @SqlUpdate("insert into something (id, name) values (:something.id, :something.name)")
    fun insert(something: Thing)

    @SqlQuery("select id, name from something")
    fun list(): List<Thing>

    ...
}
```

..I always have to do:

```
interface ThingDao {
    @SqlUpdate("insert into something (id, name) values (:id, :name)")
    fun insert(@Bind("id") id: Int?, @Bind("name") name: String)

    @SqlQuery("select id, name from something")
    fun list(): List<Thing>

    ...
}
```

Gradle has these JDBI-specific settings:

```
...
compile "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jdbi3:1.3.5"
compile "org.jdbi:jdbi3-sqlobject:3.3.0"
compile "org.jdbi:jdbi3-postgres:3.3.0"
compile "org.jdbi:jdbi3-kotlin:3.3.0"
compile "org.jdbi:jdbi3-kotlin-sqlobject:3.3.0"
....
```

The Dropwizard application has the following run configuration:

```
override fun run(configuration: MyConfig, environment: Environment) {
    val factory = JdbiFactory()
    val jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.database, "postgresql")
    // This is said to install all available plugins and is thus redundant.
    // I have tried to include various combinations of the following in
    // some desperation. None work.
    jdbi.installPlugins()
    jdbi.installPlugin(SqlObjectPlugin())  // This...
    jdbi.installPlugin(KotlinPlugin())
    jdbi.installPlugin(KotlinSqlObjectPlugin())  // ..and this alone are said to do the job
    ...
```

Otherwise, everything seems to run just fine with custom UUID mappings, Jackson Kotlin data object mapping and such.

The result of using `:something.id` in particular always is:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No argument factory registered for 'Thing(...'
```

Comment: dropwizard-jdbi3 pre-installs the SQL Object plugin for you, so you should only need to install the Kotlin plugins.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem you're seeing with binding data classes. We have a test `KotlinSqlObjectPluginTest` in the project with the exact code you posted, and it's working. I don't believe it's required for Kotlin but perhaps try configuring your Java compiler to compile with parameter names? http://jdbi.org/#_compiling_with_parameter_names

Comment: Try using `@BindBean` annotation to bind your `thing: Thing` parameter in the `insert` method. This is what the Kotlin SQL Object plugin does behind the scenes for unknown arguments.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that maybe you're using a different Jdbi instance when creating your SQL Object, than the one you're initializing in the `Application.run` method

Comment: Thanks a bunch for taking the time to comment! Your comments lead to resolving the issue, which at this point (after a couple months of fiddling) actually didn't need a fix anymore :-( I didn't get to try compiling with parameter names (comment 2). I suspected a different JDBI instance (comment 4), but couldn't see that being the problem and apparently it wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions suggested in the comments all work. Thanks very much! The trouble seemingly arose in an unfortunate sequence of adding the right libraries and fixing the code in a process that left the impression of things not working (I am still not a fan of annotation-mania).

Summary for anyone that might find anything useful in it:

1. Adding `@BindBean` made data classes work as arguments indeed.
2. Leaving out `@Bind` for arguments apparently worked for quite a while, which I just didn't notice...
3. ..possibly in parts as I incorrectly tried to use it with data classes, too: `@Bind("something") something: Thing` instead of the correct (but still unnecessary) `@BindBean("something") something: Thing`
4. Given this, removing `@Bind` and `@BindBean` worked (at least with the 1001st gradle clean build).
5. I removed `compile "org.jdbi:jdbi3-sqlobject:$jdbi_version"`, which either way doesn't seem to have any effect on things working properly (as Dropwizard is said to reference it already).

For the record, these are the dependencies that seem to work for me right now:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
  ext.dropwizard_version = '1.3.5'
  ext.jdbi_version = '3.3.0'
  ...
}

...

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

  compile "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:$dropwizard_version"
  compile "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jdbi3:$dropwizard_version"
  compile "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:$dropwizard_version"
  compile "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-views-freemarker:$dropwizard_version"
  // This is to serve static content from resources/static
  compile "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-assets:$dropwizard_version"

  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.4'
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-modules-java8:2.9.4'

  // Removed as redundant
  // compile "org.jdbi:jdbi3-sqlobject:$jdbi_version"
  compile "org.jdbi:jdbi3-postgres:$jdbi_version"
  // So, these are still required as Dropwizard doesn't know Kotlin
  compile "org.jdbi:jdbi3-kotlin:$jdbi_version"
  compile "org.jdbi:jdbi3-kotlin-sqlobject:$jdbi_version"

  // Database
  compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4'

  // ...

  testCompile "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:$dropwizard_version"

  // ...
}
```